# dropdown list not working properly on small mobile screen using react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The user experience for having a dropdown list on a small screen (mobile) is very bad using react bootstrap dropdown list.

Are there any library for this case some kind of action sheet that looks more like a natively for reactjs.

Is it possible to integrate any library that uses html,css,javascript in React?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after the Discussion I think we found the Perfect Solution for your question.

[Action Sheet Dropdown](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-actionsheet)

You can use this like ->

```
import Actionsheet from 'react-actionsheet';
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    show: false
  }

  onClick = () => {
    const { show } = this.state
    this.setState({show: !show})
  }

  onRequestClose = () => {
    this.onClick()
  }

  render() {
    const { show } = this.state

    const tip = show ? '隐藏' : '显示'
    const menus = [{content: '点我'}, {content: '不要点我'}]

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{tip}</button>

        <Actionsheet show={show} menus={menus} onRequestClose={this.onRequestClose} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This will render the UI like this

[image: UI]

Comment: this one is no different, i mean is not user friendly for a mobile screen view. I am looking for something more like action sheet style!

Comment: If you can code `CSS` or `SCSS` you can style it how you want.

Comment: I was looking for something that I dont have to make it look friendly on mobile, but is is already!4

Comment: You can give a shot to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-dropdown

Comment: is this a react or react native plugin? can I use react native for react?

Comment: yeah you can.Even the docs are using it inside a React only component

Comment: but still this is not like action sheet, i mean does not feel quite smooth on mobile , it should open in a popup and centered just like native does!

Comment: Actionsheet says is not defined!

Comment: Did you imported it?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: it should be smth like this : import Actionsheet from 'react-actionsheet';  right?

Comment: If it is working Can I get an upvote for my efforts to give you the results and also can you please accept my Answer>?

Comment: if u think that we can use react native modules in react then I can probably use this one: https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet